# Failed to create task or type oracle_sql when execute xml using ant from bash script

Tags: java, xml, bash, oracle, ant

I created a xml file with some sql file execution in my local machine. All the files are in local file path. Then created a bash script with define the execution of xml file.

Ant version

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.14 compiled on August 16 2023
```

Below mentioned the XML script.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="build" basedir=".">
           
   <target name="test">
      
      <!-- Load the data content -->
      <echo message="Start....." />
      <oracle_sql
         username="username"
         password="password"
         connect="<ip:port>/service">
         <fileset dir="C:/Work/Test" includes="test.sql" />
      </oracle_sql>
      <echo message="End....." />
      
   </target>

</project>
```

Below mentioned the bash command which is used to execute the xml file.

```
$ANT_HOME/bin/ant $* -buildfile test.xml test
```

Both xml file and bash script are in same location.
After execute the bash script, below mentioned error is appeared.

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Work\Test\test.xml:12: Problem: failed to create task or type oracle_sql
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
```

Downloaded and copy `ant-contrib-1.0.jar` to `apache-ant-1.10.14\lib`, but same issue is appeared. Any help for this issue is really appreciated.

Comment: (1) What is on `$*`? (2) Did you post your complete relevant code here? My times of using `ant` are long gone and I'm for sure no expert in this matter, but I'm pretty sure that `oracle_sql` is not a builtin task name, so you need to define it somewhere. I bet that `ant` hasn't seen a definition of this task type.

Comment: Yeah, there's no task in Ant named `oracle_sql`. Maybe you were thinking of the `sql` task? https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html